# Where should I put my properties file for tests?

Tags: java, web-applications, junit, classpath

I have a properties file that I currently have in this folder:

```
/src/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/my.properties
```

I am loading it using:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/my.properties");

Properties props = new Properties();

try {
    props.load(is);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}

String test = props.getProperty("test");
```

Now this works fine in my Spring mvc application.

But when I created a test for this, it fails and I am assuming because the way the application loads it is not using web-inf/classes since it is just a class and not a spring web app.

**So where do I put my properties file so that when my junit tests run, the properties file is picked up?**

Also, for my web app, what other folders are in the default class path other than /web-inf/classes ?

Comment: I believe your path is: `/src/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/my.properties`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put `my.properties` under `/src/test/resources` in [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), it will be available as a normal resource to your tests.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the path (/) in `classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/my.properties");` since the classloader starts in the root of the application. Keep the file in the same location as it is. Then change to

```
String filename = "my.properties"; 
InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename);  //for web-app
if(is == null)
    is = new FileInputStream (filename);        //for testing
```

Comment: but how come it is working with the / in the web-app? confused?

Comment: The classloader already searches in the root so the / doesn't make any difference. ON the other if you would try 
`class.getResourceAsStream(filename) ` searches for a resource in the same package (folder) as the class, so in that case the / would be necessary if the file was located in the root.

Answer (score 0):

Normally i put the property files directly in the src folder.